# Laravel Excel export

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

While exporting the data, it seemed to add the conditions for exporting. So, I made the constructor method and passed the data from the controller.

```
public function __construct($company_pan, $user_pan)
    {
        $this->company_pan = $company_pan;
        $this->user_pan  = $user_pan;
    }
    public function collection()
    {
        return PurchaseDetail::where([
            ['pan_code', $this->user_pan],
            ['s_pan', '=', $this->company_pan]
        ])->get();
    }
```

In the Controller,

```
    public function export(Request $request)
    {
        $company_pan = $request->pan;
        $user_pan = Auth::user()->pan_code;
        return Excel::download(new ConfirmationExport($company_pan, $user_pan), 'Confirmation.xlsx');
    }
```

All the output is blank excel. But if I changed the code in the collection of **s_pan** as

```
public function collection()
    {
        return PurchaseDetail::where([
            ['pan_code', $this->user_pan],
            ['s_pan', '=', '303030333']
        ])->get();
    }
```

It exports the data as expected. What actually the problem is?

Comment: Did you check the value of `$company_pan` in your controller? Is the `$request->pan` filled correctly?

Comment: Hi @MaartenDev, all the data seems to be fine. And also, I confirmed it by using die dump function. But the condition sucked.

Comment: so you are telling me on the CoonfirmationExport  dd($this->company_pan); is 303030333?

Comment: Yes @mrhn the data is as expected but the downloaded excel file is just empty. But works when I made the data static.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the attributes of your class? Like this?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ExampleExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $company_pan;
    protected $user_pan;

    public function __construct($company_pan, $user_pan)
    {
        $this->company_pan = $company_pan;
        $this->user_pan  = $user_pan;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return PurchaseDetail::where([
            ['pan_code', $this->user_pan],
            ['s_pan', '=', $this->company_pan]
        ])->get();
    }
}
```